Apple IIgs to VGA adapter
Are the Apple IIgs to VGA adapters straight through or have some electronics?
I see DB15 to VGA adapters on ebay for various prices, but I dont know if I need anything in particular.  Will any of these work?  Or do I need a specific type?
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2553889.m570.l1313&_nkw=apple+iigs+video+adapter&_sacat=0

The Apple IIgs generates RGB with a sync signal, so it's possible to convert to VGA with a circuit to filter/capture and then convert the sync signal to something VGA understands.
As another user alluded the big issue with this adapter (and the Apple's output in general) is that it's designed mainly for old TVs, so the horizontal sync rate is about 15kHz depending on mode. Most monitors, particular newer ones, don't support these speeds.
A good place to start would be here, which is a wiki for tracking monitors that support 15kHz and VGA input which makes them useful for early 80s computers like those from Apple, Amiga and Atari. Particularly from that list is the ViewSonic VX2476-SMHD which seems to still be available new, is relatively cheap, and is reported as being tested with the Apple IIgs.

Here we go. Add the numbers and a schematic :)

Interesting.  Doing some more research, there are adapters that people make and sell that will convert the IIgs signal to work with VGA and maybe HDMI.  Same for add in cards.  Hmm...  The cards work apparently work in all Apple IIs (except IIc, IIc+), so it would in my other Apple IIs....   I will have to ponder this.

@Keltari HDMI (usually rather DVI) will require active components for conversion, but yes, it's not as unusualy.

You need two things to be right: timing and signalling.  I don't know specifics about the IIgs but in general terms:
Most micros of that era were designed to talk to a TV.  That means whatever resolution they output had to fit within NTSC (or PAL/SECAM) timing.  Since the CRT was analogue you could vary the number of horizontal pixels as long as you had the same number of scanlines and frames as NTSC (etc) on the NTSC timing.  Sometimes you had to double scanlines if the mode was lower resolution than the available lines, and interlacing was also used.
So any display you plug this into needs to be able to accept an NTSC mode on the VGA port.  NTSC isn't a standard VGA timing - some 'multisync' monitors of the 90s would accept it, but many of today's like to scream 'no signal' if you feed it anything that doesn't pattern-match on its own supported modes.
If your monitor will display TV modes, next you need to convert the signalling to analogue VGA.  That could be composite video or RGB - that may need active components, although in some cases it can be done passively.
I think you're better off with a display that's a 'TV' - that will already know how to handle NTSC modes.  It possibly has a composite video input which you can drive directly, and perhaps an input for RGB (either RCA jacks or a SCART).  There's also a chance it will accept NTSC modes via its VGA port, but that's non-standard.
If you really want to generate honest VGA (640x480) you need a retimer - something that captures the NTSC output into a framebuffer and plays it out as a separate VGA output.  That tends to involve FPGAs and stuff, so a board rather than a cable.

A purely passive adapter would be likely to work with some monitors and not others; in cases where such an adapter works, it would be likely to produce better results than using a composite input except perhaps when running some software for older machines.  Different composite monitors back in the day would interpret an Apple II-style video signal somewhat differently, and different programs looked best on different monitors; the same remains true today.

To the point of your last paragraph, I wonder if there's an off-the-shelf component used in CCTV surveillance security systems for integrating legacy RGB cameras into a modern CCTV network.

To get from NTSC to VGA timings, you don't need a frame buffer. A line-based scan-doubler will work well enough if the input is 240p and not 480i. This is still more complex than a simple cable, but requires way less RAM and introduces less latency than buffering full frames.
